# How to display an image in a HTML widget in voila

Tags: html, python-3.x, ipywidgets, voila

I want to display an image in an HTML ipywidget rendered in [voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila). This code works in jupyter notebooks:

```
import ipywidgets as widget

img =  widget.HTML('<div id="img" style="float:left">'
                    '<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="static/test_image.jpg" alt="">'                       
                    '</div>')
img
```

But voila does not find the static file. It is displayed as a broken image.

Comment: Did you try providing the complete path (instead of the relative path)?

Comment: Yes, I did try it with an absolute path in the form src="file://C:/.../static/test_image.jpg" (which is not working in jupyter notebook)

Comment: Make sure you find the absolute path that works on jupyter notebook, and I think it will work on voila. Not sure if you need `file://` prefix

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud! You put me on the right track. I did not need an absolute path, but a base url. I have answered my question with your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jupyter notebooks and voila are running on a localhost, you can use a base url. The base url has the form 'http://localhost:/notebook/'.

Example:

```
import ipywidgets as widget

img =  widget.HTML('<div id="img" style="float:left">'
                    '<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://localhost:8888/notebooks/static/test_image.jpg" alt="">'                       
                    '</div>')
img
```